# RemoteException java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception

I'm running the program [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) on 2 JVMs on diff physical machines. I get the error

```
RemoteException
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I've even tried running it on the same machine(unchanged program) and it works but it doesnt work on diff machines. Can someone pls help me out?

@beny23- Thanks but I still end up with this error:

```
RemoteException
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorImpl_Stub
```

How can the client side have a copy of CalculatorImpl_stub?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like your not using a security manager:

Have you got a policy file (`my.policy`):

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

and run your program using

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/some/path/my.policy MyClass
```

Comment: He doesn't need either a `SecurityManager` or a .policy file to solve this problem, *unless* he is trying to use the RMI codebase feature, which isn't stated.

Comment: EJP please add more information! It sounds quite useful but i don't get it.

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem because I had different package names in client and server code:

```
package my.pkg; 
// server side interface definition...

// ------------- //

package my.pkg.something;
// client side interface definition...
```

I changed the name of client-side package and set it as the name of server-side package:

```
package my.pkg; 
// server side interface definition...

// ------------- //

package my.pkg; // renamed to the name of package in server-side .
// client side interface definition...
```

and the problem went away.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Do you have any idea of the reason for that being happening?

Comment: @RodrigoBorba No! Unfortunately I can't remember it...

Comment: Helped me with RMI cache replication in ehCache

Answer (score 9):

I had a working `RMI Client` and `Server` for my Java class. I decided to place these into their own packages rather than running as a default package.

After I placed them in their own Packages the `java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` error started happening on connection,.

I put the programs back into the default package and it all started working again.

I realize that there is probably a technical reason for this, but this worked for me!

Comment: incredible, it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are three cases.

1. If you get the error when binding to the Registry, the Registry doesn't have access to that class on its classpath or via the codebase feature.
2. If you get the error when looking up the Registry, your *client* doesn't have access to that class on its classpath or via the codebase feature.
3. If you are using the codebase feature, that in turn can be caused by the Registry *having* access to that class on its classpath, which causes it not to use the codebase, which causes loss of the codebase annotation, so your client doesn't know to use the codebase for that class.
4. If you aren't using the codebase feature, ignore the previous paragraph ;-)

Comment: just landed on this...could you kindly explain about the codebase feature that you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

i solved it with rename package name. the server and client is in two different project , but rather with same package naming.

Comment: This worked for me